# Multiple Joins With Two foreign Key in same table return zero result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and I wanted to join two table together.

(tbl_user)

```
id | user_name
6  | 11223  
5  | 3322
7  | 5566
8  | 7788
```

(tbl_friends)

i combine this two column into unique

```
user_one_id | user_two_id
5|8
5|6
```

The query:

```
SELECT user.user_name
FROM tbl_user user
INNER JOIN tbl_friends a
ON user.user_id = a.user_one_id
INNER JOIN tbl_friends b
ON user.user_id = b.user_two_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Right idea, wrong implementation.  Perhaps you want:

```
SELECT u1.user_name as name1, u2.user_name as name2
FROM tbl_friends f JOIN
     tbl_users u1
     ON u1.user_id = f.user_one_id JOIN
     tbl_users u2
     ON u2.user_id = f.user_two_id;
```

Comment: ok nice haha thanks but emm u lack one join after the tbl_friends f

Answer (score 0):

Please implement below query

```
SELECT u1.user_name name1, u2.user_name name2
FROM tbl_friends fn
        Join
     tbl_users u1
     ON u1.id = fn.user_one_id JOIN
     tbl_users u2
     ON u2.id = fn.user_two_id;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19831541)

Comment: @Sree It is an answer. If you think an answer is wrong, then downvote.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel First of all my comments is from the review. The second one I don't recommend for  `INNER JOIN `.  A downvote is needed to done by the post owner.

Comment: @Sree I came here from the review as well. And I'm pointing out that you reviewed incorrectly. This is an answer; a bad one maybe, but that doesn't warrant deletion. It warrants a downvote (and you are allowed to downvote, that is not just for the OP). If you think the answer is incorrect or otherwise bad, then downvote. You should only delete non-answers (comments or garbage), spam or link-only answers from review.